# Web application does not pick up CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am writing a web app with Flask in Python and I want to style my HTML pages with CSS but I can't manage to create a link between HTML and CSS. I've tried several times to move some files and folders and to use other means but nothing has worked.

Here is my directory:

```
App (folder):
    - main.py
    - website (folder)
        __init__.py, auth.py, models.py, views.py
        - static (folder) -> styling.css (inside)
        - templates (folder) -> base.html, home.html (inside)
```

In my 'base.html' template, I've written:

```
<script
    type="text/css"
    src="{{ url_for('static', filename='styling.css') }}"
></script>
```

But it doesn't work (when I click on the link in VSCode, it tells me that the file doesn't exist (it searches in the template folder). Do anyone see any error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong tag for including css file. You have to use link tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styling.css') }}">
```

Edit:
Another problem after including the file is that browsers save cache and sometime doesn't pick up changed static files.

For that you to hard reload or sometime clear cache.

Here is a [article](https://www.documate.org/automation/what-is-a-hard-refresh-how-to-do-a-hard-refresh-in-any-browser/) for major browsers on how to hard reload.

To see different options of reloading, open inspect tab and right click on reload button at side of search bar.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! You are absolutely right !

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with Python, but in HTML you have to import the css with the `<link/>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styling.css"> //relative link to the css
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp
I hope it works

Comment: It is exactly the right answer, thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `<head>` section in your base.html file?
It should look like this...

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styling.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
<!--Your Body Content Here -->
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, I have one, I just didn't use the <link> tag, thanks !